# dlsym Version Error When Building SVN on Solaris 10 5.10

Tags: svn, solaris

I am trying to build Subversion 1.6.9 in Solaris 10:

```
uname -a: 
   SunOS drccd 5.10 Generic_141414-10 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V890 Solaris
```

To build it I run the following:

```
export CC="gcc -I/home/susher/openssl-0.9.8l/ssl_install/include 
               -L/home/susher/openssl-0.9.8l/ssl_install/lib"
export CFLAGS="-O2 -g -I/home/susher/openssl-0.9.8l/ssl_install/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/home/susher/openssl-0.9.8l/ssl_install/lib"
export CPP="gcc -E -I/home/susher/openssl-0.9.8l/ssl_install/include"

./configure --prefix=/home/susher/SVN/subversion-1.6.9/svn_install 
            --with-ssl 
            --with-libs=/home/susher/openssl-0.9.8l/ssl_install/ 
            --includedir=/home/susher/openssl-0.9.8l/ssl_install/ 

make
```

**Note**: Line breaks in commands are for readability purposes.

OpenSSL 0.9.8 had successfully built so I am not expecting any issues to be associated with those libraries, but of course I may be wrong.

After running the commands above, Subversion starts building and about 20 minutes later the following error is output:

```
sunbox[subversion-1.6.9]: /opt/exp/gnu/bin/ld: ../../subversion/libsvn_subr/.libs
                          /libsvn_subr-1.so: dlsym: invalid version 10 (max 0)
../../subversion/libsvn_subr/.libs/libsvn_subr-1.so: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [subversion/libsvn_delta/libsvn_delta-1.la] Error 1
```

I did quite a lot of searching and could not find any information for **dlsym: invalid version 10 (max 0)**.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know, and if anyone would like to read it, I can send them the entire output of **./configure** and **make**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similair error, and it turned out that you have to use Sun's ld in /usr/ccs/bin/ld and not GNU's ld.  Recompile gcc with the option "--with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld" and have no "ld" subdirectory in the gcc source directory.  This is in fact the recommended setting, see
[Host/Target specific installation notes for GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html#x-x-solaris2)